# Importing Font Awesome to Inkscape for Icon Reference

Tags: svg, inkscape

I use Inkscape to mockup a lot, and I'd like to open the [font-awesome svg file](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/font/fontawesome-webfont.svg) so that I can have the icons ready to copy/paste into my mockups. However, upon opening this file, it seems to be empty, and none of the other files in the font-awesome font/ directory are readable by Inkscape.

How can I open the SVG file of Font-awesome with Inkscape?

Answer (score 5):

The inkscape font editor doesn't show me any of its glyphs.

What I've done is this: Create a new Inkscape file with just a simple path in it. Save and close Inkscape, open the file with a text editor. Now, open the fontawsome svg file with a text editor. Copy all the `<path>` tags, paste them inside the first file, inside the `<g>` tag. Search for "glyph", replace with "path". Save the file. Now, open this file Inkscape. All the glyphs have now been converted to path, but they sit on top of each other.

It took me about 5 minutes of moving and resizing (align + distribute helps a lot here) to rearrange all the icons to about a dozen of columns inside a page.

Comment: Are there any other steps you took? I'm trying to do the same thing and cannot get the new paths (formerly glyphs) to appear.

Comment: You need to adjust `<glyph …/>` with `<svg:path …/>` not just path. Got it to display in Inkscape 0.91 just now.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is only a font in it. Open Inkscapes' Font Editor and you will the glyphs.