# Use Font Awesome in Inkscape

Tags: fonts, svg, inkscape

Is there a way to convert Font Awesome icons to SVG graphics, so that I can use them in Inkscape inside other vector images?

[Importing Font Awesome to Inkscape for Icon Reference](https://superuser.com/questions/593510/importing-font-awesome-to-inkscape-for-icon-reference) does not help here, as this only refers to the font editor - but I just want to convert the font to a set of SVG graphics.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download raw svgs directly from the FontAwesome GitHub repository:

- [Release 5.13.1](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/c46e0ef8/svgs)
- [Latest version](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/svgs)

Comment: This can now be found at https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/c46e0ef8/svgs (Release 5.13.1)

Answer (score 23):

I use Inkscape primarily as my primary vector editor. I'm on a mac.

As far as I can tell, there's no way to just get the vectors directly into Inkscape (you'd think opening up the svg font file would give you something but nope)

Installed the otf font (again I'm on a Mac, if on Windows try other font types if you don't like the otf). 
Copy in all the characters as type.

Then "outline" them in Inkscape as you would turn any font into artwork.

This is how I got the vectors in Inkscape.

To be clear: After installing the latest Font Awesome font, I open up the Font Awesome "cheatsheet" page: http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/

I select the FontAwesome font as my font in Inkscape

I then copy the ICON itself from the the Font Awesome cheatsheet page and paste it into Inkscape as text.

Last, just "ungroup" the text selection until it becomes a pathed object.

You can then change/tweak the vectors.

Comment: works without a problem on Ubuntu. thx for the cheatsheet link .

Comment: On Ubuntu, just copy the .otf file to $HOME/.fonts and execute fc-cache -f -v to install the font.

Comment: There is a problem of encoding when I paste it directly from the website...

Answer (score 5):

You can use the "symbols" library, which is very useful.

You can import some icons, like font awesome.

This repository is great : https://github.com/Xaviju/inkscape-open-symbols

[image: inkscape symbols]

Comment: I ll give you +10 if I could ! So easy fast and far better that just font awesome icon set ! Thank a lot !

Answer (score 4):

I've added this answer to the original post as well, adding here also:

What I've done is this: create a new inkscape file with just a simple path in it. Save and close Inkscape, open the file with a text editor. Now, open the fontawsome svg file with a text editor. Copy all the tags, paste them inside the first file, inside the tag. Search for "glyph", replace with "path". Save the file. Now, open this file Inkscape. All the glyphs have now been converted to path, but they sit on top of each other.

It took me about 5 minutes of moving and resizing (align + distribute helps a lot here) to rearrange all the icons to about a dozen of columns inside a page.

Answer (score -1):

You can add it as a true-type font in Windows and then use `charmap` to find what you need.

```
C:\windows\fonts
```

---

```
C:\windows\system32\charmap.exe
```

Comment: How does this create SVG files?

Answer (score -2):

You may explain a bit better what Font Awesome is. I suppose it exists of PNG images, probably small in size. I have converted PNG and JPEG logo's to vector images, in Illustrator. I suppose the same can be done in Inkscape. It's a lot of work, and for one reasonably sized logo this is doable although it will never be perfect. For many really small images, too much work I think.

Have you contacted the creators of these images? Maybe they have them available somewhere.

You better google for vector graphics, use Google Image search with ai, eps or svg as filetype filter, and use another set.

Comment: Font Awesome is a font with vector icons, hence I doubt that it's made up of PNGs.

Comment: If it's a font, then you should be able to use it in Inkscape, type all necessary icons, then (in Illustrator slang) "create outline", or (in Inkscape language) "convert object to path". I don't know where or how, but that's the way I do it in Illustrator.

Comment: Shouldn't you answer questions that you can help with.. you don't even know what Font Awesome is!